# How can I order by a column of numbers in a base other than 10

Tags: mysql

For example, using the following query

`SELECT indicator FROM schedules ORDER BY indicator ASC;`

On the following table

```
+-----------+
| indicator |
+-----------+
| a         |
| 4         |
| b         |
| 2         |
| 1         |
| 8         |
| s         |
| 11        |
| k         |
| e         |
+-----------+
```

I get alphabetic order

```
+-----------+
| indicator |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| 11        |
| 2         |
| 4         |
| 8         |
| a         |
| b         |
| e         |
| k         |
| s         |
+-----------+
```

What i really want is this?

```
+-----------+
| indicator |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| 2         |
| 4         |
| 8         |
| a         |
| b         |
| e         |
| k         |
| s         |
| 11        |
+-----------+
```

EDIT: Numers are in base 36

Comment: Because to the computer this is not hexadecimal, or any number for that matter. It's simply text. Why are you storing numbers as text anyway? And when did `K` and `S` become part of hexadecimal representation of numbers?

Comment: How do you plan to determine the base of the numbers? You do not have k or s in hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: sorry i have adjusted the question, the numbers are actually in base 36

Comment: @Havenard the indicator field has to be short/easy to type (1233 vs Y9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are stored as text by mysql, therefore you need to convert the values to numbers in order to mysql to be able to sort it as numbers.

In mysql the [conv()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function can be used to convert numbers between bases. Convert your numbers to base 10 and interpret them as numbers (conv() returns the string representation of the results):

```
SELECT indicator FROM schedules ORDER BY CONV(indicator, 36, 10) + 0 ASC;
```

A warning: mysql will not be able to use an index to speed up the sorting operation this way. Consider storing decimal numbers or have a calculated column to do the calculation for you if you have large number of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort by length and then by the actual content. *No conversion needed!*

```
SELECT indicator
FROM schedules
ORDER BY length(indicator), 
  indicator ASC;
```